# PHP : Need to find all dates between two dates as per calendar end date

Tags: php

I need php solutions. where i will specify two dates and need to get all dates as per calendar end date.

For example :

start date : 14-Mar-2016
End date :   27-May-2016.

To create invoice i need to find all dates as per calendar end date.
Here you can see that 27-May-2016 will not get last calendar date of MAY month because specified end date is 27-May. So for that month i should get last date 27-Month.

In short,  output should like
31-Mar-2016
30-Apr-2016
27-May-2016.

Can you help me how to do  this in PHP  ?

Answer (score 1):

t returns number of days in month

```
$date = "2009-11-23";
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use date() function in different way to get your result. Please have a look on the below code, this may help you,

```
$fromDate = '14-Mar-2016';
$toDate = '27-Jun-2016';
echo date("t-M-Y", strtotime($fromDate)).' '; // show first month last date
$month_diff = (int)abs((strtotime($toDate) - strtotime($fromDate))/(60*60*24*30));
for($i=1;$i<$month_diff;$i++)
{
    echo date('t-M-Y', strtotime("+$i month", strtotime($fromDate))).' '; // in between month end
}
if(date("t",strtotime($toDate)) == date("d",strtotime($toDate)))
{
    echo date("t-M-Y", strtotime($toDate)).' '; // last month end
}
else
{
    echo date("d-M-Y", strtotime($toDate)).' '; // last date
}
```